# iOS convertPoint:fromView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code fragment in a class that is a subclass of `UIView`:

```
- (FolderWithAttachedLabel *) findFolderContainingPoint: (CGPoint) pointInWindowView
{
    BOOL endOuterLoop = NO;
    for (UIScrollView *scroller in visibleScrollViews)
    {
        for (FolderWithAttachedLabel *subfolder in expandedSubfolderLists)
        {
            CGPoint point = [subfolder convertPoint:pointInWindowView fromView:nil];
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(subfolder.bounds, point))
            {
                [subfolder removeFromSuperview];
                return subfolder;
            }
        }
        if (endOuterLoop)
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is to look through a list of folders contained in a `UIScrollView` to find the one the user is trying to drag.  `FolderWithAttachedLabel` is a `UIView` subclass. In the debugger, `subfolder` looks to be a valid instance.

The first time through the inner loop, the line:

```
CGPoint point = [subfolder convertPoint:pointInWindowView fromView:nil];
```

throws the following exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM convertPoint:fromView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa329890

Since `subfolder` is a `UIView` subclass, I'm thinking `convertPoint:fromView:` ought to be a good selector, but I'm clearly missing something.

Any suggestions here?

TIA

Comment: It looks like `subfolder` is actually an `NSArray`.  Can you post how   `expandedSubfolderLists` is created/populated?

Comment: I don't know how you picked up on it from what I posted, but you're exactly right.  I should be looking at one object out of that array.  I don't know how to flag a comment as the answer but you answered it for me.   I've messed around with this method for two hours.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: All you really had to do is read the error message you were getting. It says quite clearly that you are saying `convertPoint` to an NSArray. When the runtime tells you, "Hey, in *this* line you are making *this* mistake," it is really doing everything you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like subfolder is actually an `NSArray`.  I would suggest looking at how `expandedSubfolderLists` is populated.

For the future, you can see in the "reason" of the error:

> reason: '-[__NSArrayM convertPoint:fromView:]

`__NSArrayM` is part of the `NSArray` class cluster.